# How to export a div to PDF?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to export a `div` to PDF format.

When I click the button, a page opens to save the page in PDF or print.

This page should display the contents of the `div`, but what appears is [object HTMLDivElement]:

[image: Image with Problem]

*HTML:*

```
<div id="PDF" class="tab-pane fade in active"> 
    <div class="table-responsive panel">
       <table class="table">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Name</td>
                  <td>@Model.Name</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Adress</td>
                  <td>@Model.Adress</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" id="btnPrint" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Export"> </button>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
        var divContents = $("#PDF").html();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>PDF</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(PDF);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    });
</script>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code by replacing with the below lines

```
var printWindow = window.open('', '_self', 'height=400,width=800');
printWindow.document.write(divContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divContents = $("#PDF").html();

...

printWindow.document.write(PDF);
```

I believe you're saving the content you want to print, but not using it:

```
printWindow.document.write(divContents);
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, too! Thank you in advance for trying to help me!